# MS ACCESS - ComboBox.NotInList event doesn't work?

Tags: list, ms-access, combobox

I have a combobox with "Limit to list Yes" property and i want to allow a specific String via `NotInList` event but it still warns me..
i tried this:

```
Private Sub combo_NotInList(NewData As String, Response As Integer)

If NewData = "Check-in" Then Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot input data that is not in RowSource when LimitToList is Yes.

If RowSource is a table then data must be added to table. If data is a ValueList then it must be added to array list.

NotInList event is intended as means to add value to data source 'on the fly' during data entry.

If you don't want to have this value in table, can use a UNION query as RowSource to include "Check-in".

```
SELECT "Check-in" FROM table
UNION SELECT field FROM table;
```